# What operations are possible in concrete syntax pattern matching?

Tags: rascal

I am trying to rewrite java code using only concrete syntax (no AST). Next code works:

```
CompilationUnit rewritePackage(CompilationUnit input) = 
    visit(input) {
        case (PackageDeclaration) `package <{Identifier "."}+ N>;` => 
            (PackageDeclaration) `package <{Identifier "."}+ N>.<Identifier s>;`
            when s:= [Identifier] "othertest"
    };
```

Now I want to create `{Identifier "."}+` in order to insert it into result of rewrite:

```
CompilationUnit rewritePackage(CompilationUnit input) = 
    visit(input) {
        case (PackageDeclaration) `package <{Identifier "."}+ N>;` => 
            (PackageDeclaration) `package <{Identifier "."}+ NUpdated>;`
            when NUpdated := [{Identifier "."}+] "a1.b2"
    };
```

and it does not work. I also tried with lists, no success.

1. Is it possible somehow to create `{Identifier "."}+`? Or to convert `list[Identifier]` to it? How can I achieve `mapper( , toUpperCase)` on `{Identifier "."}+` ?
2. Is there a way to insert some str variable directly to concrete syntax?
3. In docs I found how {Identifier "."}+ can be transformed to list. But is there any other direct operations on {Identifier "."}+.
   Would be nice to have pattern match in a form: 
   `[ *Identifier firstIds, (Identifier)someName, *Identifier otherIds ]`

Comment: If you have some patience I'll try to make this clear on Thursday or Friday. You've asked a set of cohesive questions which require code examples as answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First some short answers to make things clearer:

- The implementation of the `[NonTerminal] "string"` notation is unfinished. Currently it only supports named non-terminals, such as `[Identifiers] xxx`. This is a known TODO and its already tracked as an issue.
- There is no short syntax yet for creating concrete lists. You have to construct them manually using loops or recursion. For now the advice is to:
- introduce a non-terminal name for the list in the grammar, and
- write a helper function to construct the list

To create an `{Identifier "."}+` list, use concrete syntax patterns like so:

```
syntax Identifiers = {Identifier "."}+ elems;

private {Identifier "."}+ insert(Identifier first, {Identifier "."}+ tail) 
  = (Identifiers) `<Identifier first>.<{Identifier "."} tail>`.elems;
```

The append function first wraps the list in the `Identifiers` non-terminal to be able to use the `(..)..` notation, and then projects out the new nested list using the `.elems` field. The syntax trees you produce like this are statically correct. Unlike using the `[..]..` notation which calls a parser dynamically, this `(..)..` notation calls the parser statically and composes correct trees at run-time.

Or perhaps you want to concatenate two identifier lists:

```
{Identifier "."}+ append({Identifier "."}+ prefix, {Identifier "."}+ postfix) 
      = (Identifiers) `<{Identifier "."} prefix>.<{Identifier "."}+ postfix>`.elems;
```

Sometimes you want to concatenate possibly empty sub-lists, this is allowed and the `.` separator will be removed automatically:

```
{Identifier "."}+ append({Identifier "."}+ prefix, {Identifier "."}* postfix) 
      = (Identifiers) `<{Identifier "."} prefix>.<{Identifier "."}* postfix>`.elems;
```

So to turn a `list[Identifier]` into a `{Identifier "."}` you might write this:

```
{Identifier "."}+ identifiers([Identifier head]) = (Identifiers) `<Identifier head>`.elems;

{Identifier "."}+ identifiers([Identifier head, Identifier sec, *Identifier tail])
    = append(insert(head, identifiers([sec, *tail]);
```

Agreed that this is kind of clumsy and we should maybe prioritize the much easier concrete list syntax templates syntax. We're also open to suggestions for improvement.

Comment: identifiers function does now work for me - says "splicing match not supported on Identifier". But next code worked: 

{Identifier "."}+ ids2(list[Identifier] idList) {
 idStr = joinStr(".", [ "<id>" | id <- idList ]);
 Identifiers idC = [Identifiers] idStr; 
 return idC.elems;
 }

Comment: About suggestions: I am comparing Rascal to Stratego in quesiton of rewriting programs and Stratego lacks some programming aspects of Rascal. But Rascal is more verbose - transform writers need to know the definition of syntax  - (...) ... or [...] ... - notation + **typed** pattern match in concrete syntax. It would be really nice at some point to see ability of Rascal to infer this parts automatically. Thanks.

Comment: Makes sense. We're working on type inference to make that happen, also for variables. Have a look at the relations stuff too; that's powerful.